# How to write a Feynman graph in a part page?

Tags: parts, tikz-feynman

I'd like to put a Feynman graph in the page introducing a part. Right now there is the part page, then a page with only the graph and the text begins in a third page. The code at the moment is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{luatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\part{1-loop bubble}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a1) {};
\vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
\vertex[right=2cm of a2] (a3);
\vertex[right=2cm of a3] (a4);
\diagram* {
    {[edges=photon]
        (a1) -- (a2),
        (a3) -- (a4),
    },
    (a2) -- [fermion, half left, momentum=\(k\quad m_1\), inner sep=1pt] (a3),
    (a3) -- [fermion, half left, momentum=\(p-k\quad m_2\), inner sep=1.5pt] (a2),
};

\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\chapter{Euclidean metric}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of placing the diagram in the title of the part, it might be cleaner to format the part with `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\partdiagram}{}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\Huge\bfseries}{\huge Part \thepart}{\baselineskip}{}[\vspace*{\baselineskip}\partdiagram]
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\partdiagram}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a1) {};
    \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
    \vertex[right=2cm of a2] (a3);
    \vertex[right=2cm of a3] (a4);
    \diagram* {
        {[edges=photon]
            (a1) -- (a2),
            (a3) -- (a4),
        },
        (a2) -- [fermion, half left, momentum=\(k\quad m_1\), inner sep=1pt] (a3),
        (a3) -- [fermion, half left, momentum=\(p-k\quad m_2\), inner sep=1.5pt] (a2),
    };
    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\part{1-loop bubble}
\chapter{Euclidean metric}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to place another diagram for the next part, you can renew the `\partdiagram` command just before the next `\part` command.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not loading `hyperref` or related packages and you don't want to redefine titles, you can define enclose your diagram inside command (I called `nicediagram`). Also, it's mandatory to use `protect` to avoid issues with the command when inserted in `\part`:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
%\usepackage{luatex} does nothing in my distribution, so I commented it
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\nicediagram}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a1) {};
\vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
\vertex[right=2cm of a2] (a3);
\vertex[right=2cm of a3] (a4);
\diagram* {
    {[edges=photon]
        (a1) -- (a2),
        (a3) -- (a4),
    },
    (a2) -- [fermion, half left, momentum=\(k\quad m_1\), inner sep=1pt] (a3),
    (a3) -- [fermion, half left, momentum=\(p-k\quad m_2\), inner sep=1.5pt] (a2),
};

\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\part{1-loop bubble \\[2em] \centering\protect\nicediagram}
\begin{center}

\end{center}
\chapter{Euclidean metric}
\end{document}
```

Your first page will look like that:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, the messages are `Undefined control sequence. ...bble \\[2em] \centering\protect\nicediagram}`,  `Use of \@part doesn't match its definition. ...bble \\[2em] \centering\protect\nicediagram} `,  `Missing \endcsname inserted. ...bble \\[2em] \centering\protect\nicediagram} ` ...

Comment: Are you using other packages? Is your TeX distribution updated?

Comment: The packages I am using are
`\usepackage{geometry}`
`\geometry{a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, heightrounded}`
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
`\usepackage[english]{babel}`
`\usepackage{amsmath}`
`\usepackage[overload]{empheq}`
`\usepackage{tikz}`
`\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}`
`\usepackage{amssymb}`

I think it is updated, how can I check?

Comment: Try `\part{1-loop bubble \\ \protect\nicediagram}` only

Comment: You should use `inputenc` nor `fontenc` with LuaLaTeX,

Comment: Now it works, I removed `inputenc` and `fontenc` and wrote only `\part{1-loop bubble \\ \protect\nicediagram}`. Thank you!